# Problem with .load() in jquery

Tags: jquery

Ok, I'll put my code:

```
$("#html_contenido").load("../../jsp/comun/contenedor_operativa.html" ,function(){
    $("#html_publicidad_reservar").load("../../html/pub/publicidad_reserva/publicidad_reservar_fr.html", function(){
        alert($("#html_publicidad_reservar").html());
    });
});

alert($("#html_publicidad_reservar").html());
```

The first alert shows what `publicidad_reservar_fr.html()` has inside, but the second alert doesn't show it, so in the webpage nothing appears inside `#html_publicidad_reservar`

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: do you have any javascript errors ?

Comment: yes, but they come from another page

Answer (score 3):

The second alert executes while the **A**synchronous**JAX** is still running. So the element is still empty. If you need to run code after it has been loaded, do it in your inner callback where the first alert is located.

Comment: Yes, ok everybody, but the fact is that it seems that #html_contenido is filled up with the code from the .load() instruction, as seen with the first alert (it throws the code from the .load() ), but when I see the code in the webpage, the code is not loaded. This is the real problem.

Comment: If you use "View Source" it shows the initial source, not the modified source. You need to use e.g. Firebug to see the current source.

Answer (score 1):

second `alert` run before the first one because `load` function make `Ajax` call then run the  its call back function so the scenario is

1. Load function
2. second alert
3. Finish Load
4. run callback

you can check [this](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 1):

`.load` uses ajax, which by default is asynchronous, so the first `alert` shows it AFTER the html loads, while the second alert runs before the first alert and at that time, nothing is `.load`ed yet.

Timeline is this:

1. Javascript reads the `.load` and executes it.
2. The second `alert` fires because `.load` from #1 is still happening
3. `contenedor_operativa.html` is loaded.
4. Since #3 happened and it has loaded, the next `.load` happens
5. After the nested `.load` happens, the first alert in the source code happens

What this means is, that you should put your code inside of where the first `alert` in the source code is, otherwise you're operating on non-loaded elements.

You can do `asynch:false` but that kills the whole purpose of using XHR/"Ajax"